# Как отловить prepareForSegue из другого NavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, navigationcontroller

Делаю вызов вышки так:

```
- (void)showViewWithSegueIdentifier:(NSString *)segueIdentifier {
    [self.navigationController.navigationController.topViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:self];
}
```

Пытался отловить так, но это не сработало, так как вывоз происходит из другого контроллера:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"Call");
}
```

Как это можно исправить?

Как это выглядит:
У меня есть NavigationController > MainViewController, который имеет Container View. Container View умеет > NavigationController > MenuViewController. Внутри этого container View я вставил Меню с кнопками, которые и открывают новую вюшку.

Comment: @mike, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: В чем проблема отлавливать в MainViewController ?

Answer (score 1):

Если тот UIViewController, от которого segue прокинута ничего не должен делать с destinationViewController, почему бы не отказаться от этой парадигмы и не назначить UIViewController, который нужно показать storyboardID и сделать что-то вроде:

```
MYViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"NeedeVC_ID"];
// здесь настраиваем то, что хотели настроить в prepareForSegue:, а дальше
[self.navigationController.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated: true];
// как вариант еще можно сделать [self.navigationController.navigationController setViewControllers: @[vc] animated: true];
```